# Btree Implementation in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a query for suppose if User A (not approved user) invited to User B and User C and then User C invited User D, then if User A is accepted by the Admin then below tree get approved.

I have one table of invite which contains invite_by, invite_to and is_approved.

What I have done is:

When user get approved then I am getting the id from user table and then i am accepting like that I get to do till 4 chain. But I need some good solution and doing so I am running hell lot of queries.

After a bit search I got to know I can implement Btree in postgresDB to achieve that. I know I need to implement something multi-column indexes. But I am not getting  how to implement that. Can anyone help me out on this? Or what would be better query to write on this architecture. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you need a recursive common table expression. Depending on the query plan, you create the indexes that are needed

Comment: Without more SQL in the question, we cannot say more than Frank did.